# AngularJS: Reload parent controller on state change

Tags: angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router, reload

I have some nested states as such:

```
$stateProvider.state({
    name: 'parent',
    url: '/parent',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<ui-view/>'
})
.state({
    name: 'parent.child1',
    url: '/:id/child1',
    templateUrl: 'path/to/template'
})
.state({
    name: 'parent.child1.child2',
    url: '/child2',
    onEnter: function($state, $stateParams, $rootScope, $uibModal) {
        $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'path/to/template',
            controller: 'Controller',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            size: 'md',
            backdrop: 'static'
        }).result.then(function(result) {
            if (result) {
                return $state.transitionTo("parent.child");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The second child state is a modal that, when it's form submission completes, should dismiss the modal, transition back to the first child state, and reload the first child state. To do this, I am using:

```
function close() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
    $state.transitionTo('parent.child1', $stateParams, {reload: true});
}
```

The modal closes properly, and the transition occurs, but the reload is not occurring. I have also tried using `$state.go('parent.child1', $stateParams, {reload: true});`, but the same thing occurs.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

**Update**

I was able to achieve the desired results by un-nesting the second child (i.e, changing parent.child1.child2 to parent.child2).

Technically, this is fine for what I'm doing, but I'd still rather nest them if anyone has any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

The reload property also accepts a string value so you can specify the parent state name explicitly e.g `reload: 'parent'`

Give that a try and see if it makes a difference

Comment: I tried, `reload('parent.child1')`, `reload('parent.child1', $stateParams)`, and `reload('parent')`, and, unfortunately, they all had the same result.